# Bottom TextField with SnackBar

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I want to Create an `TextField` at the bottom of the page like message app.

There is also a `IconButton`, which adds the entered text into `ListView` if `TextField` is not empty. If it is empty then it will show error in `SnackBar`.

The Problem is the `SnackBar` stacks on top of `TextField`. But I want it to be either top or bottom of `TextField`.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MainPage(),
    );
  }
}

class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainPageState createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  final _textList = <String>[];

  TextEditingController _textController;

  bool _addText(context, String text) {
    print(text);
    if (text?.isNotEmpty == true) {
      setState(() {
        _textList.add(text);
      });
      return true;
    } else {
      Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text("Invalid Text Entered"),
          behavior: SnackBarBehavior.fixed,
        ),
      );
      return false;
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _textController = TextEditingController();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Demo"),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.separated(
                itemCount: _textList.length,
                separatorBuilder: (_, __) => Divider(height: 1.0),
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
                  title: Text("${_textList[index]}"),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            _buildBottom(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBottom() {
    return Material(
      elevation: 5.0,
      color: Colors.blue[100],
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: TextField(
              controller: _textController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: "Enter Text",
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
                border: InputBorder.none,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Builder(
            builder: (context) => IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.add),
              onPressed: () {
                final success = _addText(context, _textController.text);
                if (success) _textController.clear();
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is my code in [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/8733fa747a9e13a8c597c035f3b9f98f)

Comment: I would suggest to copy here the essential part of the code.

Comment: @BadroNiaimi hmm. where can I copy?

Comment: Here in your question,  [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @BadroNiaimi More than 80% of the code is essential I believe. That is why added DartPad link instead

Answer (score 2):

try this,

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MainPage(),
    );
  }
}

class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainPageState createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  final _textList = <String>[];

  TextEditingController _textController;

  bool isVisible = false;

  bool _addText(context, String text) {
    print(text);
    if (text?.isNotEmpty == true) {
      setState(() {
        _textList.add(text);
      });
      return true;
    } else {
      Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
        new SnackBar(
          content: Text("Invalid Text Entered"),
          behavior: SnackBarBehavior.fixed,
          duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
          onVisible: (() {
            setState(() {
              isVisible = true;
            });
            Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3)).then((_) => setState(() {
                  isVisible = false;
                }));
          }),
        ),
      );
      return false;
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _textController = TextEditingController();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Demo"),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.separated(
                itemCount: _textList.length,
                separatorBuilder: (_, __) => Divider(height: 1.0),
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
                  title: Text("${_textList[index]}"),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            AnimatedContainer(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: isVisible ? 50 : 0),
              child: _buildBottom(),
              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBottom() {
    return Material(
      elevation: 5.0,
      color: Colors.blue[100],
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: TextField(
              controller: _textController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: "Enter Text",
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
                border: InputBorder.none,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Builder(
            builder: (context) => IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.add),
              onPressed: () {
                final success = _addText(context, _textController.text);
                if (success) _textController.clear();
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works pretty good. Here we are setting bottom margin which is the height of `SnackBar`. What if `SnackBar` shows message with more than one line. It will still overlap on `TextField`

Comment: ya it still overlap if your content is more than one line :(

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using `Flushbar` might help with your problem. There are many properties that you can change, such as `flushbarPosition`.

It might not solve your problem exactly how you would expect it to but it can make the Flushbar appear from the top instead of the bottom and that's one way around your problem

`Flushbar`: https://pub.dev/packages/flushbar

Comment: Thanks I will try it

Answer (score 0):

I think the best thing you can do here is to change the `behaviour` to `floating`

```dart
SnackBar(
    behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
    ...
```

Comment: even you use this **behavior** TextField still hide behind snackbar